# map iterator erase not calling appropriate destructors

Tags: c++, sfml, stdmap

`gameObjects` is a `std::map<sf::String,VisibleGameObject*>`, and `results` is a `std::map<sf::String,VisibleGameObject*>::iterator`. When this runs:

```
return gameObjects.erase(results);
```

I expected the destructor of VisibleGameObject to run, which is:

```
VisibleGameObject::~VisibleGameObject(){
    m_pSceneManager->removeSprite(name);
}
```

never runs, until the class which holds `gameObjects` is destroyed, which then runs:

```
GameObjectManager::~GameObjectManager(){
    std::for_each(gameObjects.begin(),gameObjects.end(),GameObjectDeallocator());
}

struct GameObjectDeallocator{
        void operator()(const std::pair<sf::String,VisibleGameObject*>&p) const{
            delete p.second;
        }
    };
```

then it does run. Why doesn't it run in the first case?

Using SFML 2.0

Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect a destructor of `VisibleGameObject` to run when you destroy a `VisibleGameObject*`? No `VisibleGameObject` is being destroyed, only a pointer.

Comment: Don't use naked pointers in C++. Seriously. They're hard to understand, tiring to reason about, and almost always the cause of someone's confusion.

Comment: Because I'm dumb! I've made mistakes like that so many times, I should learn!

Comment: @Kerrek - "naked pointers" - What alternatives are there?

Comment: @PigHead: a) no pointers (use automatic objects), b) no pointers (containers have their own allocators), c) no pointers (pass references as function arguments when you need reference semantics), d) smart pointers (if you really need to handle dynamic objects).

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm with you except for (c). I always pass pointers when I need reference semantics (I assume by reference semantics you mean that the argument's value is changed by the function). Otherwise you can't tell at the call site that the function changes the value, which leads to some of that tiring reasoning you mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`erase` removes the pointers from the container, but *does not* call `delete`.

Suggestion:

- change your map to simply be:

  ```
  std::map<sf::String,VisibleGameObject>
  ```

  i.e. objects not pointers to them

or:

- use a `shared_ptr`/unique_ptr (e.g.  `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depending upon availability):

  ```
  std::map<sf::String,std::shared_ptr<VisibleGameObject> >
  ```

  which *will* call the destructor

Answer (score 0):

calling erase() won't free the pointer as the implementation(map) doesn't know how the object pointed to was allocated ((example: should it call delete or free?) and more importantly it doesn't own the pointer i.e you don't transfer ownership to the container when storing pointers.

Use std::unique_ptr to wrap you pointer and then store it in the container by value. This will aid garbage collection and give you what you need.

`using VisibileGameObjectPtr = std::unique_ptr<VisibleGameObject>; 
std::map<sf::String,VisibleGameObjectPtr> gameObjects;`

`// memory will be automatically garbage collected when you erase this item. 
gameObject["key"] = VisibileGameObjectPtr(new VisibleGameObject(..args..));`